# Draggable element only drags the first time in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having troubles on figuring out what is wrong with this code : I have a `<button>` inside a `<table>` that contains an `<img>` , I want that button to be dragged multiple times.

The functions written in this code make the first drag to work but if I try to drag the element to another cell a second/multiple times, instead of getting his `id` and move the element, it returns the absolute path of the image and it does not move. The **function** `drag(ev)` sets the event target data to his `id`, then `drop(ev)` gets the data set before with `dataTransfer.getData()` and appends it to the current target with `ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))`

As you can see I can drag a button in the third `<td>` but I cannot change the position of the button again because it can only be dragged one time.

```js
var td1 = document.getElementById("1");
        td1.setAttribute("ondragover", "enableDrop(event)");
        td1.setAttribute("ondrop", "drop(event)");
        var td2 = document.getElementById("2");
        td2.setAttribute("ondragover", "enableDrop(event)");
        td2.setAttribute("ondrop", "drop(event)");
        var td3 = document.getElementById("3");
        td3.setAttribute("ondragover", "enableDrop(event)");
        td3.setAttribute("ondrop", "drop(event)");

        var btn1=document.getElementById("button-0");
        btn1.draggable = true;
        btn1.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
        var btn2=document.getElementById("button-1");
        btn2.draggable = true;
        btn2.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");

        function enableDrop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
          ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
          // ev.preventDefault();
          var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
          console.log(data);
          ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <body>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td id="1">
                  <button id="button-0">
                    BUTTON1
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td id="3">        
                   DRAG BUTTON HERE
                </td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td id="2">
                  <button id="button-1">
                    BUTTON2
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML code as well?

Comment: @NehaSoni the elements of the HTML are created dinamically with JavaScript, it's an 8x8 table it's too long a code to write

Comment: How can we reproduce your issue?

Comment: @NehaSoni I added the HTML, hope that the issue is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the drag handler is defined on the `button` element, the drag event target will be the `img`. [There's more on event propagation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/21146235)

You can hop up the element hierarchy yourself to find the `button` element you're expecting, e.g.:

```js
function drag(ev) {
  let elt = ev.target;
  while (elt && !elt.hasAttribute("draggable"))
    elt = elt.parentElement;
    
  if (elt)
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", elt.id);
}
```